# Install Android SDK during Maven build

Tags: java, android, maven, robolectric

I am trying to automate testing for my Android app using Maven and Robolectric. The problem that I have is that I won't be running the tests on my local machine and the Android SDK won't be installed on the machine running the tests. I have used the maven-dependency-plugin to grab the sdk from our repository and unpacked it in the process resources phase, the problem is that this occurs after the need to access the files. When I try to use the apk packaging it never gets to the SDK download because it can't find the SDK. So my question is this: Is it possible to trigger this download before anything else happens in the build? If anybody has any light to shed on how to properly install the sdk at build time it would be much appreciated. Let me know if I can add any additional information.

Comment: Short answer is no, this is impossible within maven's predefined life cycle.

Comment: Could you explain why? I'm not great with Maven and such.

Answer (score 0):

Both Robolectric and maven-android-plugin both need SDK. Android plug-in requires build tools/adb while Robolectric needs the corresponding android.jar.

So, you'll have to create maven tasks/goals for:

1. Download SDK zip from some url.
2. Unpack the zip on test machine, in a directory.
3. update the `android.sdk.path` property of POM, to point to sdk directory.

Some snippets I found, might help:

Download:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>download-android-sdk</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>download-single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://dowloadsite.com/<url>
                <fromFile>/downloads/sdk.zip</fromFile>
                <toDir>${project.build.directory}/sdk</toDir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unpack:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-sdk</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/sdk/sdk.zip" dest="${project.build.directory}/sdk/" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I've actually done all of those things already. The problem, as I mentioned, is that it's not happening until after it is needed, I will try the pre-integration-test phase as you have listed though.

Comment: No luck with changing the phase.

Comment: @user2483079 How about `validate` phase ?